# Reset the TabNavigator history with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following structure:

```
    const routeConfiguration = {
        Login: { screen: Login },
        Home: { screen: TabBar },
    };

    const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
        headerMode: 'screen',
        navigationOptions: {
            header: { visible: false }
        }
    };

export const RootNav = StackNavigator(routeConfiguration, stackNavigatorConfiguration);
```

My TabBar where each Tab has it's own StackNavigator:

```
const routeConfiguration = {
    TabOneNavigation: { screen: TabOneNavigation },
    TabTwoNavigation: { screen: TabTwoNavigation },
    TabThreeNavigation: { screen: TabThreeNavigation },
};

const tabBarConfiguration = {
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        inactiveTintColor: 'lightgray',
        labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 10,
            fontFamily: Fonts.book
        },
        style: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.greenLightGradient,
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderTopColor: Colors.tabGreenLine
        },
    }
};

export const TabBar = TabNavigator(routeConfiguration, tabBarConfiguration);
```

When the app first load It goes to Login screen. After successful login I use actionTypes.TO_HOME to go to Home. There I have 3 tabs (Feed, Suggestion, Profile). Inside Profile tab I have Log Out button pressing on which I reset the navigation history and go to Login Again (so far so good). But when I login again and go to Home, it shows the first tab for a second and navigates me to the last one (Profile) which looks like the TabNavigator's history is not resetted. Should I do something special so that the TabNavigator's history is also resetted?

This is my reducer for resetting the history and going to the Login screen:

```
export const navReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    let nextState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.TO_LOGIN:
            nextState = RootNav.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE, routeName: actionTypes.TO_LOGIN })],
                    key: null
                }), state);
            break;

        case actionTypes.TO_HOME:
            nextState = RootNav.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE, routeName: actionTypes.TO_HOME })],
                }), state);
            break;

        default:
            nextState = RootNav.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
            break;
    }

    return nextState || state;
};
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the index 0 on navigate action

Comment: It's not working. The effect is the same. I updated my question with more info and code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an React-Navigation v5 Example, to clear all History:

```
navigation.dispatch((state) => {
      return CommonActions.reset({
        ...state,
        history: state.history
          ? [
              state.history[
                state.history.length - 1
              ],
            ]
          : undefined,
      });
    });
```