# Reset stackNavigation when changing TabNavigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I would like to know how reset my stack navigation when a changing my tabNavigation. I try to use type="reset" but nothing happen

try :

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
              <Scene key="root">
                <Scene
                  key="tabbar"
                  tabs={true}
                  type={ActionConst.RESET}
                  tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
                >
                  <Scene key="osu" title="OSU" icon={TabIcon} type={ActionConst.RESET}>
                    <Scene 
                      key="scarlet"
                      component={ScarletScreen}
                      title="Scarlet"
                    />
                    <Scene
                      key="gray"
                      component={GrayScreen}
                      title="Gray"
                    />
                  </Scene>
                  <Scene key="vu" title="VU" icon={TabIcon}>
                    <Scene 
                      key="blue"
                      component={BlueScreen}
                      title="Blue"
                    />
                    <Scene
                      key="black"
                      component={BlackScreen}
                      title="Black"
                    />
                  </Scene>
                </Scene>
              </Scene>
            </Router>
          );
    }
}
```

I can pass to gray from scarlet and when i change top i want reset stack to scarlet.

Someone know ??

Comment: You can check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496739/reset-navigation-history-to-login-screen-using-react-navigation/43497435#43497435 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763054/reset-the-tabnavigator-history-with-react-navigation

Comment: that is rect-navigation i am on rect-native-router-flux

Comment: Then, it's a good idea to say that in the description :)

Comment: it's tagged sorry